# PHP Imagick converting RGB to CMYK difference between computers

Tags: php, imagick

I am reading in an SVG using RGB color scheme and converting to a JPG with CMYK using Imagick library in PHP. It was all working properly on my local machine and others, however when I deploy this to the server the colors get messed up (a blue color is getting much darker).

Below is my conversion code:

```
// start conversion to JPG
$image = new Imagick();
$image->setBackgroundColor(new ImagickPixel('white'));
$image->readImageBlob(file_get_contents('../assets/Map.svg'));

// finalize settings of the JPG
$image->transformImageColorspace(imagick::COLORSPACE_CMYK);
$image->setImageFormat("jpg");
$image->setImageCompressionQuality(100);
$image->setImageUnits(imagick::RESOLUTION_PIXELSPERINCH);
$image->setImageResolution(100, 100);

$filename = $company_id . '-Map.jpg';
$image->writeImage("../maps/" . $filename);
$image->clear();
$image->destroy();
```

The colors in the SVG are like the following: style="fill: #193B71;"

My first thought was related to the versions of the software and they seem to be very close though not identical:

Local Machine:

- PHP 7.2.1
- imagick module 3.4.3
- ImageMagick 6.9.6-2 Q16 x86_64 2017-11-27
- GPL Ghostscript 9.20 (2016-09-26)
- Mac OS 10.11.6

Remote Server:

- PHP 7.0.27
- imagick module 3.4.1
- ImageMagick 6.7.8-9 2016-06-16 Q16
- GPL Ghostscript 9.20 (2016-09-26)
- CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core)

I was wondering if the ImageMagick version is the issue here before going through the process of upgrading that on the server? Or if anyone had a suggestion of what else to check against as I'm not entirely familiar with all the tools the php imagick module might be using to make this conversion.

Comment: As far as I know converting between CMYK and RGB is not a direct/exact process and depends on color profiles. Cursory googling seems to indicate that JPGs may or may not include embedded color profiles, so if yours doesn't imagick will likely fallback to whatever default is available. [Relevant CLI option](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#profile), [maybe relevant PHP function?](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.setimageprofile.php)

Comment: I believe there were a lot of changes in the v6.7 version of Imagemagick. I would try to get Imagemagick and Imagick updated on the server.

Comment: IM 6.7.8.9 is known to have bugs. I would do as Bonzo said and try to upgrade to as high a version as you can go. The current version is 6.9.9.34. So you are well over 200 versions old. If you cannot upgrade, perhaps downgrade to 6.7.7.x, such as 6.7.7.10